# Resizing of GridView columns are no longer allowed after adding style to the GridViewColumnHeader

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a grid view with 4 columns.

```
        <ListView Grid.Row="0" Name="CallHistory" ItemsSource="{Binding CallDetails}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListViewItemStyle}" SelectionChanged="CallHistory_OnSelectionChanged"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="#FF474747" Foreground="White">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListColumnHeaderStyle}">
                    <GridViewColumn Width="150"  Header="Year" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Year}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="85"  Header="Time(sec)" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Duration.TotalSeconds, StringFormat={}{0:F2}}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Width="200"  Header="Caller" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CallerName}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Width="Auto"  Header="Receipient" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ReceipientName}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Added a style to it in App.xaml

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}" x:Key="ListColumnHeaderStyle">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="WhiteSmoke" Background="Transparent">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="ContentHeader" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Padding="5,5,5,0" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" TextAlignment="Left" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    </Style>
```

With the above code, the user won't be able to resize the columns anymore. If I comment the "Template" and "OverridesDefaultStyle" setters in the style, I will get the non-styled GridView which I can resize. I want to keep the style along with column resize feature. Please let me know what I need to do for it.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add the `PART_HeaderGripper` when you overrode the `GridViewColumnHeader`'s `ControlTemplate`:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}" x:Key="ListColumnHeaderStyle">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="WhiteSmoke" Background="Transparent">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="ContentHeader" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" Padding="5,5,5,0" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" TextAlignment="Left" />
                        </Border>
                        <Thumb x:Name="PART_HeaderGripper"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                               Margin="0"
                                />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
    </Style>
```

[Full `ListView`'s Style and Template for reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/listview-styles-and-templates)